# Charging 12 volt SLA batteries

Tags: batteries, charging

I’ve recently discovered the use of SLA batteries for my boat but know nothing about them. I have a full size 12 volt digital smart charger which I can set as low as 2 amp. It automatically shuts down and cycles when the battery is charged. It works great on my flooded 12 volt batteries. Can I use this charger on SLA 12 V, 9 Ah batteries?

Comment: Please provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet or user's manual for the charger.

Comment: A rule of thumb is charge at 1/10 the A/h rating. Based on that, 2A is too much. If your charger doesn’t have a setting or is not intended for SLA batteries, then it is not recommended you use it.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I’ll be getting a separate charger then. I’ve been reading since I posted this and now trying to figure out what’s best a cv charge or cc while trying to figure out now what charger to select.